# MySQL command, without using Manual input

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysqlcommand

How to create a table which is included this by MySQL command without using Manual input, see the pic blow:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBpMK.png)

Comment: try this: `ALTER TABLE table_name ADD is_published BOOLEAN DEFAULT true;`

Comment: I have no idea what this question is about please try to clarify.

Comment: Despite that this question needs more clarification, but if you are using `phpmyadmin`, you can always `show the SQL` that being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this SQL to create a table name as: published

```
CREATE TABLE published (
  `is_published` BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT true
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the accepted answer, it seems you want the SQL commands that are run by the graphical interface. In the future, you can use phpMyAdmin to show you those queries directly.

When you're on that page to create a new table (or edit an existing table), there's a "Preview SQL" button next to "Save". Clicking that shows the SQL commands that will run, but won't actually run them.

[image: Create table dialog]

[image: Preview SQL results]